# How to read a list from json object in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-layout

I have data in json format where one field `subtitle` has list of data again. How can I iterate through this list which already inside a list. here is the code.

#Data.json

```
[
    {
        "id":0,
        "title":"Heading",
        "subtitle":[
            "sub1",
            "sub2",
            "sub3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":1,
        "title":"Heading1",
        "subtitle":[
            "sub4",
            "sub5",
            "sub6"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "title":"Heading2",
        "subtitle":[
            "sub7",
            "sub8",
            "sub9"
        ]
    }
]
```

#list.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new HomePage()
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() => new HomePageState();
}

class Location {
  final String id;
  final double lat;
  final double long;

  Location({this.id, this.lat, this.long});
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  List data;
  Future _future;
  List<Location> locations;

  Future<String> getData() async {
    var response = await rootBundle.loadString('asset/sample.json');
  
    this.setState(() {
      data = jsonDecode(response);
    });
    
    for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
      print( data[i]["subtitle"]);
    }
    
    
    return "Success!";
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    this.getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Listviews"), backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
          return new Card(
            child: new Text(data[index]["title"]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to list the items in `subtitle`. How can I do it?

Comment: try this: `data[index]["subtitle"][subtitleIndex]` subtitleIndex is an int from 0 to 3 in your case.

Comment: I tried this. The problem is how can I put the subtitle index in loop. Shall I use nested loops?

Comment: Yes you can use a nested loop for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this with a column for example:

```
Column(children: [
    for ( var subtitle in data[index]['subtitle'] ) Text(subtitle)
  ],
),
```